# Find the nth derivative of $\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $nth$ derivative of $\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}.$

I tried solving this problem by simplifying the given expression $\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}.$ Now, $\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{\frac 13 (x-\frac 13)}{x^2+x+1}.$ So, if we are able to find the $nth$ derivative of $\frac{x-\frac 13}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{x-\frac 13}{(x+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34},$ then we are done.But I am not finding any productive way of solving or proceeding it further as it *doesn't give us something helpful* such that it reduces to one of the standard form whose nth derivatives are known. I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Note that after a change of variable, this amounts to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241760/n-textth-derivative-of-tan-1-x + https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447694/find-the-nth-derivative-of-y-frac-xx2a2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the roots of $x^2+x+1$ and apply partial fractions. We will call the roots of the denominator $a,b$
$$\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{3x-1}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{3a-1}{a-b}\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{3b-1}{a-b}\frac{1}{x-b}$$
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{1}{x-a}=\frac{(-1)^n\space n!}{(x-a)^{n+1}}$$
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{3x-1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{3a-1}{a-b}\frac{(-1)^n\space n!}{(x-a)^{n+1}}-\frac{3b-1}{a-b}\frac{(-1)^n\space n!}{(x-b)^{n+1}}$$$$=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{a-b}\left(\frac{3a-1}{(x-a)^{n+1}}-\frac{3b-1}{(x-b)^{n+1}}\right)$$
$$a,b=\frac{-1±i\sqrt3}{2}$$
We can easily induce a general strategy by following the same method. We start by factoring the denominator and applying partial fractions, allowing us to use the formula from earlier
$$\frac{mx+b}{(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac{mr+b}{r-s}\frac{1}{x-r}-\frac{ms+b}{r-s}\frac{1}{x-s}$$
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{mx+b}{(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac{mr+b}{r-s}\frac{(-1)^n\space n!}{(x-r)^{n+1}}-\frac{ms+b}{r-s}\frac{(-1)^n\space n!}{(x-s)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: yes. we substitute the roots back into the equation @Franklin

Comment: That's a beautiful insight you gave me. A nice strategy for solving this. Thank you!

Comment: Can you suggest me a general strategy to transform $\frac{ax+b}{px^2+qx+r}$ in general , into a suitable form like the one you did above?

Comment: @Franklin is that ok?

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! That was a great help to me. I remain indebted and grateful to you and this cant be expressed in mere words as I am falling short at it...